# Problems with ICEFaces components

Tags: jsf, tomcat

I need some help, i'm trying to develop a simple application using JSF 1.2, ICEFaces 1.8, but i keep getting all type of errors.
I went to icefaces website and download a input file example but it didn't work, here's the

```html
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/ICEFaces_1.8] threw exception [null] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitImpl.createResponseWriter(RenderKitImpl.java:169)
 at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.D2DRenderKit.createResponseWriter(D2DRenderKit.java:87)
 at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:168)
 at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderView(D2DViewHandler.java:151)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:106)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:251)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:144)
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:245)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2555)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2544)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Like the example in website i got two files for the froent-end, Index.jsp and basicInputFile.jspx.

Index.jsp

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ICEfaces Component Showcase</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <jsp:forward page="basicInputFile.iface" />
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
<f:view xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component">

        <ice:outputDeclaration doctypeRoot="HTML"
                               doctypePublic="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
                               doctypeSystem="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"/>

    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"></meta>
            <title>InputFile Component Tutorial</title>
            <link href="./xmlhttp/css/xp/xp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        </head>

        <body>
            <h2>Basic InputFile Component</h2>

            <ice:inputFile id="inputFileComponent" 
                           actionListener="#{user.uploadActionListener}" />
            <ice:message for="inputFileComponent" />

            <ice:outputText value="#{user.currentFile.physicalPath}" />
        </body>
    </html>
</f:view>
```

and finally, my web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.PersistentFacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup> 1 </load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Blocking Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.BlockingServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup> 1 </load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.iface</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Blocking Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/block/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="1.2"
              xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd">

    <managed-bean>
        <description>
            Backing bean for inputFile example.
        </description>
        <managed-bean-name>user</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>
            user
        </managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

Libs:
icefaces-comps.jar
icefaces.jar
jstl.jar
backport-util-concurrent.jar
commons-fileupload.jar

Anyone know to make it work?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stackoverflow em Português. Queira traduzir a sua pergunta para português ou faze-la em [http://www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Thank you, i'll